# How do I keep state between requests in AppEngine (Python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm writing a simple app with AppEngine, using Python. After a successful insert by a user and redirect, I'd like to display a flash confirmation message on the next page.

What's the best way to keep state between one request and the next? Or is this not possible because AppEngine is distributed? I guess, the underlying question is whether AppEngine provides a persistent session object.

Thanks

Hannes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No session support is included in App Engine itself, but you can add your own session support.

[GAE Utilities](http://gaeutilities.appspot.com/) is one library made specifically for this; a more heavyweight alternative is to use django sessions through [App Engine Patch](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/).

Comment: Another good option is Beaker, which supports datastore, memcache, and encrypted cookie sessions.

Comment: Great, thanks! gaeutilities does exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 3):

The ways to reliable keep state between requests are memcache, the datastore or through the user (cookies or post/get).

You can use the runtime cache too, but this is very unreliable as you don't know if a request will end up in the same runtime or the runtime can drop it's entire cache if it feels like it.

I really wouldn't use the runtime cache except for very specific situations, for example I use it to cache the serialization of objects to json as that is pretty slow and if the caching is gone I can regenerate the result easily.

Comment: Ah, maybe I answered too fast. But surely this applies to implementing sessions too.

Comment: Koen's right, the easiest way would be use a URL param or cookie.  Just make sure you cleanse it properly for XSS and/or use a mapping of codes to messages or something.  Beyond that, look to a custom session solution using memcache or datastore.